# How can a novice integrate reCAPTCHA v2 into a website built with a CMS?

Tags: html, content-management-system, recaptcha

I want to first start off by pointing out I am a complete self-taught novice when it comes to HTML and web development. I have a history of inspecting code and trying to learn what lines create which element and saving offline versions of websites to mess with later.

I am trying to integrate reCAPTCHA v2 into my workplace's website on our user-submitted forms to reduce the severe amount of spam submissions. The website is built through a 3rd party and we have a fair amount of customization ability through the SilverStripe CMS. We have created forms that allow us to include an HTML block anywhere in the makeup of the form, and in the draft I can successfully create the reCAPTCHA checkbox. Unfortunately, the 3rd party that does the support and heavy lifting charges us for use and maintenance of a reCAPTCHA.

For the most part, I'm testing all of my attempts on my [personal test website](http://dcproject.host20.uk/home.html?). The issue that my novice level of knowledge can't piece together is how to get the **server-side validation.** I haven't yet figured out what code I need to plug into my HTML block to get the response from Google, or where to plug in my secret key. The guides provided [Google's reCAPTCHA site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/) provide the base tools but it's just not quite enough for me to piece it together.

I've noticed a lot of people use php packages, but I don't **think** I can use php in this fashion through SilverStripe, but I also have limited knowledge of implementing php in websites.

My apologies if this was a wordy post, but many thanks for any help anyone can offer!